# Android Application class killed and starts periodically

Tags: android, android-application-class

I am working on an Android application that most it logic is done in background and basically analyzing the user activities (walking, running, in_vehicle etc)..
The ui has only 2 screens for basic setup and for giving permissions.

In the Application class onCreate (not Activity) the app register to ActivityRecognition api and gets the ActivityDetected events in a broadcast receiver which process the DetectedActivity and so on.

The app has also a boot complete receiver, after device boot, the receiver onReceive invoked.. This, causing the Application class to start, onCreate is invoke, the ActivityRecognition begins as described. This works perfectly!

So actually, the process starts in boot complete and nothing stops it..

Additionally, in the Application onCreate I send a firebase analytics Event (like AppStarted)
Also, when ActivityRecognition registration done I send another event (like ActivityDetectSuccsesfullySrarted)

Now here is the thing, in firebase I see that these events are sent about 20 times a day!!

Is there explanation for this?
This means that something, kills and recreate the process? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Android [terminates unused processes to free up system memory](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle).

If you want a process to run for a long time on an off-the-shelf Android device, you will need to use [a foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services). If you are working with your own custom firmware, you could take other steps to try to keep your process around.

Comment: Thanks, so if it killed by the system, who restarts it again?

Comment: @MotiBartov: I can't really answer that. If you are using any APIs that take a `PendingIntent` as a parameter, something tied to those could be restarting your process after it was killed.

Comment: Well yes, the ActivityRecognition API takes a PendingIntent with BroadcastReciever for DetectedActivity updates